# firestore image not load to profile page

Tags: image, firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

when i try to pull profile image from firestore daatabse, It show following error on profile page
'package:flutter/src/painting
_network_image_io.dart':
Failed assertion:line22
pos14:'url!=null':is
not true.
See also:
https://flutter.dev/docs/testing/errors

although it gives this error if i press ctrl+s it loads the profile page. This is my code.

```
 String profilePicUrl;
 @override
 void initState() {

super.initState();
FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser().then((user){
  profilePicUrl=user.photoUrl;
}).catchError((e){
  print(e);
});
```

}
and then i put profilpicUrl inside of networkImage, as follows

```
    Container(
                width: 150.0,
                height: 150.0,
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                  image: DecorationImage(
                    image: NetworkImage(profilePicUrl),
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(75.0)),
                  boxShadow: [
                    BoxShadow(
                      blurRadius:7.0,
                      color:Colors.black
                      )
                      ]

                ),
              ),
```

Every time i run the App i have to press ctrl+s to prevent the error and load the profile page

Comment: The code you shared is reading the profile image for a user from Firebase Authentication, not from Firestore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The image is not loading in time, first the `initState` is getting called and the `build` method is getting called before the image is received. Therefore, you can use `FutureBuilder`:

```
Container(
        width: 150.0,
        height: 150.0,
        child: FutureBuilder(
          builder: (context, AsyncSnapshot<FirebaseUser> snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
              return Image.network(profilePicUrl, fit: BoxFit.cover);
            } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.none) {
              return Text("No data");
            }
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          },
          future: FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser(),
        ),
      ),
```

Comment: @vindi96 since the answer helped you please upvote it so others know that it is helpful thank you!